# I try to create facebook login. How to solve this issue?

Tags: dart, flutter

I try to create facebook login. How to solve this issue?

//Facebook Login
               FlatButton(
                child: Text('Login by Facebook' ),
               color: Colors.blue,
               textColor: Colors.white,
                onPressed: (){

```
            facebookSignIn.logInWithReadPermissions(['email','plublic_profile'])
              .then((result) {
                 switch (result.status) {
                 case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:

               FirebaseAuth.instance
                     .signInWithFacebook(
                         accessToken: result.accessToken.token)
                 .then((signedInUser){
                   print('Signed in as ${signedInUser.displayName}');
                   Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/home');
                 }).catchError((e){
                   print(e);
                 });
               }});
              },
          ),
```

[facebooklogin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v04VP.png)

Comment: Try to add another cases

Comment: Have you asked to google first? Or put your code

Comment: Your error is blocking your code